# remove element frome array of string

Tags: java, arrays, string

I made a function to delete a specific element in the array, but the problem that am struggling with is that when we getting the value of the element that we want to remove from s.next() it's not removing but when we already initialized a value for it it is removing

for example, we have a function remove

```
 public static String[] remove(String[] element, String value) {

        int validSize = 0;
        String[] n_elements = new String[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            if (element[i] == value) {
                element[validSize] = element[i];
                validSize++;
            }

            n_elements = new String[validSize];
            if (validSize >= 0) System.arraycopy(element, 0, n_elements, 0, validSize);


        }

        return n_elements;
    }
```

in main

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

 
    String[] group_A = {"Alexandr", "Ahmed", "Maria", "elf", "Omar", "Mariam"};

    Scanner s  = new Scanner(System.in);     

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group_A));

    String value = "elf";
```

//we already initialized a value for it

```
    group_A = remove(group_A,value);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group_A));
}
```

}

output is correct

```
[Alexandr, Ahmed, Maria, elf, Omar, Mariam]
[Alexandr, Ahmed, Maria, Omar, Mariam]
```

but if  we get value from the user in put it does not deleting

```
 String value = s.next();
```

output is

```
[Alexandr, Ahmed, Maria, elf, Omar, Mariam]
elf
[Alexandr, Ahmed, Maria, elf, Omar, Mariam]
```

Comment: Try to compare String using .equals() method, the "==" compare the references not the content of the Strings .     element[i] == value  ===> element[i].equals(value)

Comment: in remove method?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: in any place , when you like to compare the content of two Strings , use the method ".equals()" , the "==" is used to comapre if two strings are exactly the same object in the memory . in your case you have two string that have the same content but every one is an independent object in the memory , you need to read about hw to compare String in java and try to read about String Pool in java to more understand .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Like @[Oussama ZAGHDOUD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69582328/remove-element-frome-array-of-string/69582577#comment122989618_69582328) said,

Instead of  `if (element[i] == value)` ,  Use  `if (element[i].equals(value))`.

Comment: in this case, its only print the specific element that we want to delete

Comment: [Alexandr, Ahmed, Maria, elf, Omar, Mariam]
input >> elf
output >>[elf]

Answer (score 0):

Your code miss a "!" before the condition and you need to use .equals() instead of"==":

```
public static String[] remove(String[] element, String value) {

        int validSize = 0;
        String[] n_elements = new String[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
            if (! element[i] .equals( value )) {
                element[validSize] = element[i];
                validSize++;
            }
            n_elements = new String[validSize];
            if (validSize >= 0) System.arraycopy(element, 0, n_elements, 0, validSize);
        }
        return n_elements;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     String[] group_A = {"Alexandr", "Ahmed", "Maria", "elf", "Omar", "Mariam"};
        Scanner s  = new Scanner(System.in);     
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group_A));
        String value = s.nextLine();
        //we already initialized a value for it
        group_A = remove(group_A,value);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(group_A));
}
```